# Filling a 2D array with characters using data input from file - Java

Tags: java, arrays, nullpointerexception

I am trying to fill an array of chars using data input from file, while parsing the file I am also trying to store some values, but things are not working.

This is my code:

```
    File file = new File(filename); // filename is a user input
    Scanner fileScan = new Scanner(file);   

    // determine the board size
    ROWS = fileScan.nextInt();
    COLS = fileScan.nextInt();
    fileScan.nextLine();

    char[][] board = new char[ROWS][COLS];    

    for( int row = 0; row < board.length; row++){
        for (int col = 0; col < board[row].length ; col++){
            if (fileScan.hasNext()) {
                board[row][col]= fileScan.next().charAt(0);
                if(board[row][col] == START){
                    startingPoint = new Point(row, col);
                }                   
                if(board[row][col] == END){
                    endingPoint = new Point(row, col);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Given that then input file has

```
2 2
1 O O 
O O O 
O X 2
```

this is what i get when I run it (when I try to print the array):

```
     O O 
     O X 

   java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.awt.Point.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at CircuitBoard.getStartingPoint(CircuitBoard.java:139)
    at CircuitTracer.<init>(CircuitTracer.java:120)
    at CircuitTracer.main(CircuitTracer.java:36)
```

What is going wrong that prevents me from getting a value for the startingPoint ?

Comment: Where are you instantiating your fileScan object?

Comment: Please edit the full stack trace of the exception into your question.

Comment: Is it a square matrix always/?
Put up the code of fileScan instantiation

Comment: not sure if this has effect (did not trace all the code) your file says 2 lines, 2 cols, while the data are 3 lines and 3 cols.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, i have tried to run the code:
taking in consideration my comment about data size `2x2 --> 3x3`

it worked OK

the file should be

```
3 3
1 O O 
O O O 
O X 2
```

reading code is fine,
and this is the array printing code i used

```
for( int row = 0; row < board.length; row++){
    for (int col = 0; col < board[row].length ; col++){
        System.out.print(board[row][col] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println("");
}
```

this was the output:

```
1 O O 
O O O 
O X 2
```

so if this is what you need, just change 1st line in file to `3 3`
and use the print code in this answer